# Design Pattern Advise

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an class with a method which accepts an argument of particular type. The behavior of the method should be dependent on the specific class. For example,

```
public void doSomething(SomeInterface t) {
    ...
}
```

Depending on the actual class of the argument, I need the behavior to change. I need the outer class to perform an action based on the values found in T. Specifically, the outer class needs to construct a Hibernate criteria object which has restrictions which depend on the type of T, which is an implementation of a "Query" interface. The outer class is an implementation of a parameterized builder interface which constructs instances of objects which can be used to execute queries against a data store (for example, Criteria for hibernate, a `SearchQueryBuilder` for elasticsearch, etc). So as you can see, the problem with having t do the work is that it would require knowledge of HOW to construct these criteria which is beyond its intended purpose of just containing information about WHAT to query

It feels dirty and wrong to do something like

```
if (t instanceof X) { 
    ...
} else if (t instance of Y) {
    ...
}
```

I see a couple problems here.

1. This requires previous knowledge about the types being passed in
2. The class is not "closed for modification" and will require a modification every time a new type needs to be supported.

Can someone suggest a good design pattern that can be used to solve this problem? My first thought is to use a factory pattern in combination with strategy and create instances of the class with a "handler" for a specific type. Another thought I had was to create a mapping of Class -> Handler which is supplied to the class at construction time.

Ideas appreciated.

Comment: Your strategy pattern has already been an excellent way!!

Comment: Take a look at the "visitor pattern". Maybe that's the pattern you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest idea would be to put the logic in the implementations of `SomeInterface`:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    public void actOnUsage();
}

public class SomeOtherClass {
    public void doSomething(SomeInterface t) {
        t.actonUsage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I need the outer class to perform an action based on the values found in T. Specifically, the outer class needs to construct a hibernate criteria object which has restrictions which depend on the type of t

Comment: t is an implemenation of a "Query" interface. The outer class (SomeOtherClass in your case), is an implementation of a parameterized builder interface which constructs instances of objects which can be used to execute queries against a data store (for example, Criteria for hibernate, a SearchQueryBuilder for elasticsearch, etc). So as you can see, the problem with having t do the work is that it would require knowledge of HOW to construct these criteria which is beyond its intended purpose of just containing information about WHAT to query.